# Congratulations to MVP group 2017

Tags: discussion, mvp

Join me in Congratulating Adrian  and Eliot Harper for being so awesome part of this community and well deserved MVP Title for Winter 2017.If I have missed anyone else who was awarded for first time MVP Title please forgive my ignorance and let us know .

[Introducing Our Winter 2017 Class of Salesforce MVPs](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/02/winter-2017-salesforce-mvps.html?d=70130000000tP4G)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well done [Adrian](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2995/adrian-larson) and [Eliot](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper)!

Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks guys. I wouldn't be here without SFSE and all the great questions you ask.

Comment: Well deserved on both counts!

Comment: Thanks, it's a privilege to be invited to the MVP program and be recognised for my contribution.

Comment: Well deserved! and my voting to Adrian also counted. Good Job guys!!!

Comment: Congrats guys. so much contribution to SFSE. Keep it up the good work guys

Comment: Congrats Adrian & Eliot - well deserved! Keep up your fantastic work!

Comment: Congrats @AdrianLarson & Eliot. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Congratulations @AdrianLarson !

Comment: Congratulations @EliotHarper !

Comment: Congrats AdrianLarson and Eliot Harper! Keep up the good work.

Comment: Great work @AdrianLarson and Eliot Harper - see a few more names I know from the community in London I had better congratulate too.

Comment: Congrats guys! We also got our very first European Non-Profit MVP too!

Comment: These guys have being selflessly contributing to sfse to make it better every day. Cheers to these folks. Not all heros wear capes.